# fxml view won't update: How can I get my controller to update my 1st view after processing a call from my 2nd view?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a controller with a view that has a combobox with customernames, both generated by FXMLLoader. When I click the "create new customer' button, `newCustomerPane()` is called which opens a 2nd view. This view allows the user to define and add a new customer. When the user is done (clicks on "save") `addCustomer()` is called which adds the new customer to the database. `addCusomter() then calls`update` which fills the combobox in the 1st view with an updated list of customers.

The problem is that the 1st view simply doesn't update. I've tried updating the 2nd view as a test and that seems to work fine. I also tested if the controller succeeds in adding the customer to the database and that works fine too. I'm also sure that the controller manages to retrieve the ew updat from the database.

Here is the method that instantiates the controller and the view:

```
public class Run extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("ProjectBeheer.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene)
    primaryStage.show();
    ProjectBeheerController projectBeheerController=loader.getController();
}
}
```

Here is my controller:
    public class ProjectBeheerController {

```
CustomerDAO customerDao = new CustomerDAO();

@FXML Button editBtn;
@FXML ComboBox<String> klantCB;
ObservableList<String> obList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("klant1","klant2");
@FXML Button newCustomer;
@FXML Button newProject;
@FXML Button newSprint;
@FXML Button newUserStory;

Stage customerStage = new Stage();
@FXML TextField custName;
@FXML TextArea custDescription;
@FXML Button custAddBtn;
@FXML Button custCancelBtn;

public ProjectBeheerController() {
    klantCB = new ComboBox<String>();
}
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    klantCB.setValue("klant");
    update();
}
private void update(){
    ArrayList<CustomerModel> customers = customerDao.getCustomerList();
    ObservableSet<String> observableSet = FXCollections.observableSet();
    for(CustomerModel customer: customers) {
        observableSet.add(customer.getCustomer_name());
    }
    klantCB.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(observableSet));
}
public void newCustomerPane(){
    try {
        Parent root = null;
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ProjectBeheer_KlantEditor.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        customerStage.setScene(scene);
        customerStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void addCustomer(){
    custName.setText(custName.getText()+" update!");
    customerDao.addCustomer(custName.getText(),custDescription.getText());
    this.update();
    hideCustomerPane();
}
}
```

I've searched the internet for a solution, but no one seems to share this problem. I hope anyone can help me. Feel free to ask for code if you want to see more.

Comment: Post the controller for the second FXML.

Comment: There is none. I use one controller for both. If I'd use a 2nd controller for the 2nd view then I wouldn't know how to update the 1st view. Keep in mind that the 2nd view is meant to be like a pop-up box.

Comment: "I use one controller for both". Actually, you don't; you have two controllers. What I think you mean is that both controllers are instances of the same class. That will get *really* confusing. Use a different controller *class* for each FXML file, and pass data between them in the [usual way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310#14190310). You can also consider using `showAndWait()` instead of `show()`, which might make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried to do as you say, and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I will mark this question as a duplicate of that one, so that others who have similar questions will be more easily directed to that question (and its excellent answer).

Comment: y'know, In hindsight I should've searched a bit better before asking. Sorry for wasting your time.